# instead of mb_strtolower()?

Tags: php, string

GoDaddy doesn't provide an mbstring module for shared hosting. But I have to use `mb_strtolower()`.

I'm working on `utf-8` charset, what can I use instead of `mb_strtolower($string,'UTF-8')`?

Edit: I will convert Polish chars.

Comment: As a work around, you could take advantage of the SQL `LOWER()` and `SET` your encoding. I have no experience in this, therefore this is just a possibility which might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See FluxBB's UTF-8 module: https://github.com/fluxbb/utf8

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could you try using PCRE functions like so:

```
$string_lower = preg_replace('/^(.*)$/', '\L$1', $string);
```

Comment: yes it's working but on most simple string. you are right, it's not working properly.

Comment: yes, i said this is not working properly. i am looking for some other methods instead of that.